# No update on my RecyclerView and No errors are visble

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-sqlite

This portion comes from "edicionCliente." If I'm not mistaken, it displays data, and that's it. There's also a floating action button located in the bottom left corner of the screen. When you tap this button, it will switch to the "formActualizaProducto" activity. This is where you can update the data, and the changes you make will be reflected in the recyclerView.

```
if (savedInstanceState==null){
            Bundle datosAdicionales = getIntent().getExtras();
            if (datosAdicionales!=null){
                identifyProducto=datosAdicionales.getInt("identificadorProducto");
            }
        }else {
            identifyProducto=(int)savedInstanceState.getSerializable("identificadorProducto");
        }
        uConexion comunicacionVisualizaProducto = new uConexion(edicionDatos.this);
        SQLiteDatabase accionVisualizaProducto = comunicacionVisualizaProducto.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursorProducto =accionVisualizaProducto.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_NAME+" ORDER BY idTabla DESC",null);

        if (cursorProducto.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                campoIdClienteEdicion.setText(cursorProducto.getString(1));
                campoPrecioEdicion.setText(cursorProducto.getString(2));
                menuZonaEdicion.setSelection(cursorProducto.getInt(3));
                menuPaisEdicion.setSelection(cursorProducto.getInt(4));
                menuTipoProductoEdicion.setSelection(cursorProducto.getInt(5));
                menuCanalVentaEdicion.setSelection(cursorProducto.getInt(6));
                menuPrioridadEdicion.setSelection(cursorProducto.getInt(7));
                presentadoraImagenEdicion.setImageURI(Uri.parse(cursorProducto.getString(8)));

                //Quitar el acceso al teclado
                campoIdClienteEdicion.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
                campoPrecioEdicion.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
                menuZonaEdicion.setSelection(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
                menuPaisEdicion.setSelection(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
                menuTipoProductoEdicion.setSelection(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
                menuCanalVentaEdicion.setSelection(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
                menuPrioridadEdicion.setSelection(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
            }while (cursorProducto.moveToNext());


        }
        cursorProducto.close();

        btnEnviarEdicion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent xcv = new Intent(edicionDatos.this,formActualizaProducto.class);
                xcv.putExtra("identificadorProducto",identifyProducto);
                startActivity(xcv);
            }
        });
```

This part is from formActualizaProducto

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Bundle datosAdicionales = getIntent().getExtras();
            if (datosAdicionales != null) {
                identifyProducto = datosAdicionales.getInt("identificadorProducto");
            }
        } else {
            identifyProducto = (int) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("identificadorProducto");
        }


        uConexion comunicacionVisualizaProducto = new uConexion(formActualizaProducto.this);
        SQLiteDatabase accionVisualizaProducto = comunicacionVisualizaProducto.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursorProducto =accionVisualizaProducto.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_NAME+" ORDER BY idTabla DESC",null);

        if (cursorProducto.moveToFirst()){
            campoIdProductoCambio.setText(cursorProducto.getString(1));
            campoPrecioProductoCambio.setText(String.valueOf(cursorProducto.getInt(2)));
            menuZonaCambio.setSelection(cursorProducto.getInt(3));
            menuPaisCambio.setSelection(cursorProducto.getInt(4));
            menuTipoProductoCambio.setSelection(cursorProducto.getInt(5));
            menuCanalVentaCambio.setSelection(cursorProducto.getInt(6));
            menuPrioridadCambio.setSelection(cursorProducto.getInt(7));
            presentadoraImagenCambio.setImageURI(Uri.parse(cursorProducto.getString(8)));
        }
        cursorProducto.close();
        btnGuardarCambios.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.M){

                    //validamos si el usuario ya brindo acceso...
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(formActualizaProducto.this, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                        capturarFoto();


                    }else{
                        //aca se lanza un dialogo para que el usuario acepte usar el modulo correspondiente....
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(formActualizaProducto.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},permisoCamara);
                    }

                }else{
                    capturarFoto();
                }



                //Try y cath
                try {
                    int precioProducto = Integer.parseInt(campoPrecioProductoCambio.getText().toString());

                    accionVisualizaProducto.execSQL("UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME +
                            " SET idCliente='" + campoIdProductoCambio.getText().toString() +
                            "', precioProducto=" + precioProducto +
                            ", zonaProducto='" + menuZonaCambio.getSelectedItem().toString() +
                            "', paisProducto='" + menuPaisCambio.getSelectedItem().toString() +
                            "', tipoProducto='" + menuTipoProductoCambio.getSelectedItem().toString() +
                            "', canalVentaProducto='" + menuCanalVentaCambio.getSelectedItem().toString() +
                            "', prioridadProducto='" + menuPrioridadCambio.getSelectedItem().toString() +
                            "', fotografiaUbicaciones='" + ubicacionFoto+
                            "' WHERE idTabla=" + identifyProducto);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(ex);
                }
                Intent finalizarCambio = new Intent(formActualizaProducto.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(finalizarCambio);

            }
        });

    }
    private void capturarFoto() {
        // Código para capturar la foto

        Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (i.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            File imagenArchivo = null;
            try {
                imagenArchivo = crearArchivo();

                // Asegúrate de tener la ruta de la imagen
                ubicacionFoto = imagenArchivo.getAbsolutePath();

                // Lanza la cámara y espera la foto
                Uri fotoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(formActualizaProducto.this, "com.example.mieroles", imagenArchivo);
                i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fotoUri);
                startActivityForResult(i, codigoServicioCamara);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }
    //el siguiente metodo, asigna el nombre a la foto recuerden que es por fecha y hora
    private File crearArchivo() throws IOException {
        String horaFecha = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMmdd_Hh-mm-ss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        String nombreImagen = "IMG_"+horaFecha;

        //creamos la foto.....
        File nuevaUbicacion = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File imagenFinal = File.createTempFile(nombreImagen,".jpg",nuevaUbicacion);

        //obtener la ruta....
        ubicacionFoto=imagenFinal.getAbsolutePath();
        return imagenFinal;

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (permissions.length >0 && grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            capturarFoto();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(formActualizaProducto.this,"Es necesario confirmar el permiso",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

I've tryed with some recommendations that ChatGPT gave me but I honestly don't know why my formActualizaProducto is not working well if I have no errors.

Comment: Just In case here it is the link to the project:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZQbtFEtms8MfnCHbQ4QlHe6ARsvZHtHp/view?usp=sharing